# Equivalent of search_data() in Drupal 8

Tags: search, 8

Is there any function equivalent to the (D7) search_data() in Drupal 8? I would like to get the search results as a renderable array or html for a given keyword programatically.

In D8, the SearchController.php provides the view which does the same, but I'm not sure how to call that from my module?

It uses

```
$plugin = $entity->getPlugin();
$plugin->setSearch();
$plugin->buildResults();
```

to get the result.

How do I create the SearchPageInterface entity which contain the getPlugin() method? Or is there a way to create an instance of the default search plugin directly?

My requirement is to show the search results in a custom page where the search results are wrapped by the custom page content. I've implemented this in D7 using search_data function. How can I achieve similar result in D8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create the search page entity, you load it. SearchPage::load($id). Either hardcode the id that you use on your site or make it configurable through configuration/settings/URL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try to get the default search page using SearchPageRepository::getDefaultSearchPage() and load it with SearchPage::load($id). Will update the results here.

Comment: Thanks, the SearchPage::load($id) is working. I'm not able to figure out the right method to get the default search page. SearchPageRepository::getDefaultSearchPage() is not working. The getDefaultSearchPage execute a query with $this->getQuery() and the getQuery() returns the query object from $entity_manager->getStorage('search_page'); which is set by the SearchPageRepository constructor. I am not able to figure out how to load the $entity_manager so that I can call getStorage('search_page');

Comment: That is a service. See search.services.yml on how it is defined. You don't need to create the object yourself, just access that service, with \Drupal::service('search.search_page_repository') or by injecting it into your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [hook_search_page](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!core!modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_page/8) to Override the rendering of search results.

You could also look into [search_data](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21core%21modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_data/8) API.

Comment: This will not work. 1) The search_data() is not there in D8. 2) I do not want to override the search results, but use it with in my custom menu.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, by example:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('type', 'article')
->condition('title', 'cat', 'CONTAINS')
$nids = $query->execute();
```

Return a list of node ids where the field "title" contain the word "cat".
After you can use:

```
$nodes = entity_load_multiple('node', $nids);
```